# login Authentication via roles is not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I am in a serious issue with the school based application, I want to set up like the roles based system for Admin, Student and the Teacher. I have used devise for authentication and cancan for the authorization. The thing is I don't no where to start. I have added the devise user model and added an field roles. I followed [this](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) for the role based authorization. It works, but when I try to login with the Student credential by selecting a Teacher role in the drop down it never validate the roles(never says access denied for you something like that). It login as a student. I want to validate the selected roles in the login form.

By now I am using User model as the devise model. and
has Student Model , Teacher Model , and the Admin Model. and the all Student, Teacher and the admin belongs to the User.

In User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :admins
  has_many :students
  has_many :teachers
  ROLES = %i[admin teacher student]
end
```

In my devise registration view

```
<%= f.collection_select(:role, User::ROLES, :to_s, lambda{|i| i.to_s.humanize}) %>
```

Or else do I want to use devise model for all Student, Teacher and Admin? if yes how do I complete that. Any help or suggestions are helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a specific role user to login with the role selected in the form dropdown then you have to customize the login method SessionsController#Create for the role selected in the login form with the user credentials coming from the form and send an error warning and avoid user to get logged in.

A sample sessions#create method will be :

```
def create
 self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
 if resource.role == params[:role]
  set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 else
  set_flash_message!(:error, "UnAuthorized Access!")
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```